# Java / No campaign available for requested device model

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, vert.x, nosuchelementexception

I think that this following error message might be specific to the project that I am working out upon, but, by any chance does any one know what might be the cause of this following error message and how to deal with it?

> post DynamicAdRequest failed
>
> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Sequence contains no elements
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:115)
>
> at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:176)
>
> at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:64)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:246)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:169)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
>
> at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:176)
>
> at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:64)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:246)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:169)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.slowPath(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:106)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:63)
>
> at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:32)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:24)
>
> at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>
> at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
>
> at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>
> at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>
> at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352)
>
> at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
>
> at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
>
> at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
>
> at com.samsung.dsp.dbhandler.SqlConnectionProvider.getDeviceGroup(SqlConnectionProvider.java:114)
>
> at com.samsung.dsp.networkrequesthandler.RequestHandlerVerticle.dynamicAdRequestHandler(RequestHandlerVerticle.java:135)
>
> at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.api.contract.openapi3.OpenAPI3RouterFactory$6.handle(OpenAPI3RouterFactory.java:241)
>
> at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.api.contract.openapi3.OpenAPI3RouterFactory$6.handle(OpenAPI3RouterFactory.java:239)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:219)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:85)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:133)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.api.validation.impl.BaseValidationHandler.handle(BaseValidationHandler.java:89)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.api.validation.impl.BaseValidationHandler.handle(BaseValidationHandler.java:19)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:219)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:85)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:133)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.ResponseContentTypeHandlerImpl.handle(ResponseContentTypeHandlerImpl.java:54)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.ResponseContentTypeHandlerImpl.handle(ResponseContentTypeHandlerImpl.java:28)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:219)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:120)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:133)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.doEnd(BodyHandlerImpl.java:231)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.end(BodyHandlerImpl.java:211)
>
> at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.lambda$handle$0(BodyHandlerImpl.java:74)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.handleEnd(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:417)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleEnd(Http1xServerConnection.java:482)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleContent(Http1xServerConnection.java:477)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.processMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:458)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:144)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:712)
>
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:619)
>
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.lambda$channelRead$1(VertxHandler.java:146)
>
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
>
> at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
>
> at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:144)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
>
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
>
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: even if no one has seen this specific error message, you might solicit more feedback on your issue if you elaborate a bit more about what your application does, under what circumstances the error is logged, etc...

Comment: It is not an error message, but rather quite normal behaviour only. A device will be used for advertising campaign only if it is of a valid model, whose model name has been specified in the device database. If I specify an invalid model, then it is quite normal to get this error message only. Apart from the device model, the same can be said for the other attributes of the device that are available in the device database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Observable.concatMap()` with an empty list of observables. Without seeing your code, we can't narrow it down any further.

Comment: I am working out with code written by someone else and I am just trying out to compile and execute the project for the first time. Code is confidential property of company and I am not supposed to share it with anyone who is outside of the company. I anyway thank you for your response, upvote and accept your answer. Once again, thank you for your input.